# Generate "batch_size" many random variables in Keras Lambda layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Is there any possibility to generate a separate random variable for each element in a batch in a Keras Lambda layer?

I am implementing a network and try to stay completely with Lambda layers rather than custom layers, however I am not able to use tensors as shape inputs to any random variable generating function of keras.backend, and there is no function like e.g. random_like(sample_tensor).

Of course I can also provide the random variables as inputs, but it seems like a severe shortcoming of the current architecture so maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a GaussianNoise (https://keras.io/layers/noise/) Layer with the same shape as your layer and then merge them together using a concatenate (https://keras.io/layers/merge/) layer. In a Lambda Layer you can then seperate the input from the output using indexing.

Comment: I also thought of something in that way, but I need uniformly distributed variables (one per image in the batch), so now I just feed them as input. Thank you nevertheless.